# How can I use negative lookbehind to exclude fractions?

Tags: regex-lookarounds

I have a list of measurements that need to be deconstructed into quantity (numeric) and unit (string).  Things like

```
1 gal.
500lbs
none
2.25gal
4feet twine
2lbs regular and 2lbs lite
```

All was well and good using `\d+(\.\d+)?`, but now I have a fraction thrown into the mix:

```
3/4gal
```

I need to exclude the fraction from this search so that I can deal with it separately.  I'm successfully excluding the numerator (`3`) by inserting a negative lookahead-- `\d+(?!\/)(\.\d+)?`, but I can't figure out how to exclude the denominator (`4`).  I think I'm supposed to use a negative lookbehind but I can't figure out how.  `\d+(?!\/)(?<!\/)(\.\d+)?` and `\d+(?!\/)(\.\d+)?(?<!\/)` still match the `4`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a construct like this `\d+(?!\/)(?<!\/)(\.\d+)?` the lookbehind `(?<!\/)` is always true as the only thing you can match (not assert) before is a digit.

You might also exclude a `/` on the left of the digits part, and add the lookahead after matching the decimal part.

```
(?<!/)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!/)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!/)` Negative lookbehind, assert directly to the left of the current postion is not `/`
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Match an optional `.` and 1+ digits
- `(?!/)` Negative lookahead, assert directly to the right of the current position is not `/`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p7x8JJ/1)

Comment: I'm still having trouble breaking down & understanding the logic -- I'm new to regex -- but it works :)

Comment: @JJL I have added a breakdown of the parts in the pattern.

Comment: Very kind! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can match and skip all occurrences of `[digits]/[digits]` pattern:

```php
\d+\/\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WeKeuR/1).

The `\d+\/\d+(*SKIP)(*F)|` part matches one or more digits, `/`, one or more digits, and then `(*SKIP)(*F)` makes the regex engine fail the match and start searching for the next match from the failure position, so the `3/5`-like substrings won't be able to mess with your output.

Comment: Ahhh,  I really like this.  But sadly I'm working with python `re`, which doesn't support `(*SKIP)` and `(*F)`.  Not able to install any other libraries so can't use pypi `regex`.

Comment: @JJL Not a problem, install `pip install regex` and then use `import regex as re`, and it will work. Or do you want `/3gal` to not match?